# Did I do this Set Theory proof right?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

so i was asked to prove $z \cap(s \cup t ) = ( z \cap s ) \cup (z \cap t)$

my proof was as follows:

set set $z \cap(s \cup t ) = ( z \cap s ) \cup (z \cap t)$ must contain the set $z$
since $ z \subset  (z \cap  t )$ and $ z \subset  (z \cap  s )$

the set must contain $s \cup t $ beacuse the set is an intersection of two sets both containing s and t

since the set contains $s \cup t $ and $z$ the set can be written $z \cap(s \cup t )$

please tell me if i did this right / what i could do better

Comment: Please rewrite your post so that it is clear what "the set" is. Also, in general it is not true that $z\subset (z\cap t)$, the opposite inclusion holds though.

Comment: $(z\cap s)\cup (z\cap t)$ does not have to contain $s\cup t$! But I think you have the right idea. Usually with these kinds of proof "A=B" for sets A and B it is best to start with an element in A and show that it must be in B and the other way around.

Comment: I'd suggest you try element chasing: $$x\in \Big(z\cap(s\cup t)\Big) \iff \Big((x\in z) \text{ and }  (x\in  s\text{ or } x\in t)\Big)$$.  Continue with in that manner...

Answer (score 0):

> set $z \cap(s \cup t ) = ( z \cap s ) \cup (z \cap t)$ must contain ...

Here you are **assuming** they are equal, although that's the very thing you're trying to prove. That is a logical fallacy.

> $z \subset  (z \cap  t )$ and $z \subset  (z \cap  t )$

That is false. Both of them. Here the inclusion is in the opposite direction: $z\supset z\cap t$ and $z\supset z\cap s.$

> the set must contain ...

**Which** set must contain whatever it is you're saying it must contain? Do you mean $z \cap(s \cup t )$ must contain something? Or $( z \cap s ) \cup (z \cap t)$ must contain something?

That those two are equal is something that you do not know until you have proved it.

> since the set contains $s \cup t $ and $z$ the set can be written $z \cap(s \cup t )$

But the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ "contains" (I prefer to say "includes") the set $\{1,2\}$ and the set $\{5,6\}$ but nonetheless the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ cannot be written as $z\cap(\{1,2\}\cap\{5,6\},$ no matter what set $z$ is.

If you want to prove $z \cap(s \cup t ) = ( z \cap s ) \cup (z \cap t),$ you should attempt to prove that every member of $z \cap(s \cup t )$ is a member of $( z \cap s ) \cup (z \cap t)$ and also that every member of $( z \cap s ) \cup (z \cap t)$ is a member of $z \cap(s \cup t ).$